# AWS Lambda returns "Unable to import module"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running the AWS DevSecOps project present [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/implementing-devsecops-using-aws-codepipeline/):

In the `StaticCodeAnalysis` stage of the pipeline I am getting AWS Lambda function failed.

On checking the log the error is:

> "Unable to import module `cfn_validate_lambda`: No module named cfn_validate_lambda".

I checked that the S3 bucket that has the python code Zip and also ensured that the zip file has `Public` in the permissions.

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you sort out this? I'm also facing similar issues. Please post what you have done if yes. @Vaidya Siva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to package and zip the dependencies carefully...

The problem lies in the packaging hierarchy. After you install the dependencies in a directory, zip the lambda function as follows (in the example below, lambda_function is the name of my function)

Try this:

```
pip install requests -t .
zip -r9 lambda_function.zip .
zip -g lambda_function.zip lambda_function.py
```